How can we express the idiom "go through the motions" in Latin?
I know that this idiom means to do something without enthusiasm or perfunctorily. The translation into Portuguese will depend on the context.
Since the adverb "perfunctorily" comes from "perfunctorie" in Latin and the verb "perfungor" means something like "go through, could we just use the verb or a construction with "perfunctorie" and the verb "agere"?
English isn't my native language.

Dr. Traupman's dictionary translates "perfunctorily" as parum dilgenter, and "perfunctory" as parum diligens.
I would translate "they as just going through the motions" as parum diligentes funguntur.
